# Remove outliers from training data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scipy, outliers

Assuming I have a pandas dataframe, I use the following to remove outliers:

```
y = df['Label']
df = df.drop(['Label'], axis=1)
new_df = df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df)) < 3).all(axis=1)]
```

Since I don't want to include `'Label'` column in the process, how to also remove the outlier labels?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the remaining index to match the new df and Label column:

```
new_df.join(y)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just perform the zscore calculation on the columns with a numeric dtype. No need to drop the "Label" column before hand.

```
new_df = df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df.select_dtypes("numeric"))) < 3).all(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

With the `autooptimizer` module, you can easily remove outliers from your dataset.
It uses the Interquartile range method to remove outliers

```
pip install autooptimizer 

from autooptimizer.process import outlier_removal 

outlier_removal(data)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).